# How to limit the number of share options in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How to limit the number of share options in ActionBarSherlock. I only want to show a few but at the moment I am getting the complete default list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShareActionProvider` -- both the native one and the ActionBarSherlock backport -- do not appear to have a means to limit the overall number of choices, other than by having a more targeted `Intent`.

`ShareActionProvider` *may* elect to show a subset initially, with some sort of "More..." option, after the user has made some choices, via `setShareHistoryFileName()`. That should happen automatically, unless you disabled it via `setShareHistoryFileName(null)`.

You are welcome to take the source code to `ShareActionProvider` and come up with your own UI (e.g., always only show four entries plus a "More...", regardless of history).

Comment: Thanks I will have a look the options you suggested